# I can't launch a online pdf named in Chinese via LaunchUriAsync

Tags: c#, uwp, launcher

As captioned, I'm trying to create a UWP app, I want to use `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` API to launch an online pdf named in Chinese, but it always returns `false`.

```
 var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions()
 {
     ContentType = "application/pdf"
 };

 options.UI.PreferredPlacement = Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Above;
 var flag1 = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(
     new Uri("http://testserver/web/public/a.pdf"), options);
 var flag2 = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(
     new Uri("http://testserver/web/public/中文.pdf"), options);
```

The flag1's value is `true`, but the flag2 is always `false`.
Actually the `a.pdf` and `中文.pdf` are the same pdf, and I can open `http://testserver/web/public/中文.pdf` via IE browser.

Please give me some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to use URL encoding to encode these characters so that they are safe for use in URL:

```
var chinese = Uri.EscapeUriString("中文.pdf");
var flag2 = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(
       new Uri("http://testserver/web/public/" + chinese));
```

Although I must mention I could open the example URL in the question successfully even without encoding it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but failed. I not sure it's my adobe problem or not.

Comment: BTW, my win10 version is 1703, OS build version is 15063

Comment: If you set the default PDF viewer to Microsoft Edge, does it work?

Comment: I can open the Chinese pdf via IE browser directly.

Comment: I meant if you change the default app for `.pdf` files in Windows and then try the `LaunchUriAsync` - does it work and return `true`?

Comment: if I set the default APP to Edge, the flag is true but can't render the PDF. I change the default APP to IE, the flag is false.

Comment: It really seems there is a problem with the file. Alternative solution could be to first download the file (for example in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`) and then use `Launcher.LaunchFileAsync()` to open it. That might work. You can use `BackgroundDownloader` or `HttpClient` to download the file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806178/how-to-download-files-using-uwp-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, I already take the workaround solution as you said in my code. And actually the a.pdf is the same as the 中文.pdf, I just changed the pdf name.

Comment: hmm that is very interesting. Maybe this was fixed in newer versions of Windows 10, as it works as expected on my PC even with the chinese characters in filename. Do you happen to have a chance to test on a newer version?

Comment: what's your win10 version? I can't do the testing on my working device.

Comment: I have the latest release (April 2018 update), but it was taken down temporarily because of update issues

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try to do the test.