# How to combine audio and video tracks for playback or get StorageFile from the web?

Tags: c#, uwp

I develop YouTube UWP client and I need to combine video and audio tracks (muxed files are only with 480p and lower). But I can't get `StorageFile`'s because of `PathTooLongException` (url length is about 800 characters)

I use Visual Studio 2019 Preview on x64 machine. Minimum target version is Fall Creators Update and target is October 2018 update.

What did I try:

- Upgrade minimum version to October 2018 Update
- Use `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(Uri)` instead of `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(string)`.

Then it rises

> System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

According to Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> this exception may be caused by framework incompability but in UWP apps there is no obvious way to directly change target framework.

Here's my code:

```
MediaComposition muxedStream = new MediaComposition();

BackgroundAudioTrack audioTrack = await BackgroundAudioTrack.CreateFromFileAsync(await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(audioInfo.Url));   //Trying to get file throws an exception
MediaClip videoTrack = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(videoInfo.Url));

muxedStream.BackgroundAudioTracks.Add(audioTrack);
muxedStream.Clips.Add(videoTrack);

videoSource.SetMediaStreamSource(muxedStream.GenerateMediaStreamSource());
```

I need to somehow bypass this exception or find another way to combine streams.

Url sample: https://r9---sn-n8v7znsz.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mime=video%2Fmp4&expire=1546167117&lmt=1543098677581810&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C298%2C299%2C302%2C303&sparams=aitags,clen,dur,ei,expire,gir,id,ip,ipbits,ipbypass,itag,keepalive,lmt,mime,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,requiressl,source&key=cms1&pl=24&ipbits=0&txp=5532432&keepalive=yes&itag=137&requiressl=yes&ei=7U4oXNOULs-fyAWHl74I&ip=95.47.116.128&c=WEB&gir=yes&dur=274.999&id=o-ACk7-_Fgu_caJbjuRbtlayK-dgmNtLEqypLyLfwWbA2j&signature=8173BAF30157D47064F9BE1DB85CB5A910AA5008.28DA3ACEEE47AD89D56E1F162602C99D73751E02&source=youtube&clen=102247371&fvip=15&video_id=xO_XyOsHK6A&title=WOLFENSTEIN+2+SONG+%28COLOSSAL+CARNAGE%29+LYRIC+VIDEO+-+DAGames&rm=sn-uixgxjvh-ig3e7e,sn-3c2ed7y&fexp=23763603&req_id=69d1c8f74394a3ee&redirect_counter=2&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mip=5.187.79.66&mm=29&mn=sn-n8v7znsz&ms=rdu&mt=1546157635&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjA0LnN2bzA2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&ir=1&rr=12 (976 characters)

Comment: Could you use `HttpClient` instead, and use `StorageFile` with a stream from an `httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`?

Comment: Don't use StorageFile to download a web resource.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37806443/17034

Comment: @HansPassant, I do not need to download files. I need to stream them. At least because downloading will take much more time than streaming and combining them on the run

Comment: @Matthew, could you provide a bit more details, please?

Comment: That's awfully vague, google something like "uwp stream audio" to find relevant hits.

Comment: @HansPassant, Yes. But I need to stream both audio and video track which contained in separate files to the player at the same time. The code I've provided in the question work but if I use local files or remote files with shorter urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another solution.

Unfortunately, `StorageFile` cannot be gotten from the web. But I can use two different players linked with one timeline controller. Here's more detailed solution: [How to play video and audio from separate URLs in UWP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276649/how-to-play-video-and-audio-from-separate-urls-in-uwp-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

`StorageFile`.* is for directly accessing files in the in the UWP app's sandboxed file system; accessing files in known folders it has declared Capabilities for; or for making a copy of picked files **not** for downloading/streaming stuff fromt the Internet.

I quote:

> [**StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync)
>
> Gets a StorageFile object to represent the file at the specified path.
>
> **ArgumentException`**
>
> The path **cannot be** a relative path or **a Uri**. Check the value of path.

...and

> [**StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync)
>
> Gets a StorageFile object to represent the specified Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) app resource. For examples of sample URIs see [Load images and assets tailored for scale, theme, high contrast, and others.](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/app-resources/images-tailored-for-scale-theme-contrast)
>
> `var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("ms-appx:///datafile.xml") // <----- SEE` 
> `Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).done( /* Your success and error handlers */ );`
>
> **You can use this method to access your app's resources** using either "ms-appx://" or "ms-appdata://" Uniform Resource Identifier (URI).

OP:

> But I can't get StorageFile's because of PathTooLongException (url length is about 800 characters)

That's a bit of a hint because Windows file system max path is about 255 characters hence why you are getting the error too.  It's straight-out rejecting it before it even realises that it's not a path.